# Concerning the use of relative pronouns

Tags: relative-clause, relative-pronouns

The relative pronoun *quem* in the following seems to function in a way that I wouldn't normally associate with relative pronouns:

> Et accipiens puerum, statuit eum in medio eorum: *quem cum complexus esset*, ait illis:...

What strikes me as odd is that the dependent clause seems to be set off by both *quem* and *cum*.

The point becomes clearer when the phrase "*quem cum complexus esset*" is compared with the Greek for which it is a translation: καὶ ἐναγκαλισάμενος αὐτὸ. In the Greek, instead of a relative pronoun, a personal pronoun is used; i.e. αὐτὸ instead of *quem*, and the clause is set of by the participle without any interference by a relative pronoun.

Because of this, I'm led to think that *quem*, in this particular case, should be thought of more as a personal pronoun than a relative pronoun.

Although it seems to refer back to an antecedent, it doesn't seem to set off the dependent clause (which seems to be the role of *cum*) as relative pronouns often do, i.e. by establishing it as a dependent clause and tying it with the rest of the sentence. I hope that makes sense.

**My question is:** Am I thinking about this correctly? Should pronouns such as *quem* sometimes be thought of as more like personal pronouns?  Is this a frequent type of construction in Latin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relative pronoun can also be used to start a new independent clause, and in this use it doesn't really function as a relative pronoun in the usual sense.
This is sometimes known as a connecting or connective relative pronoun, and is often best translated as if it was *is*, *ille*, or similar.
The same applies to relative adverbs like *quo* as well.
See part F of [Allen & Greenough §308](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/allen-greenough/Chapters/Chapter-308.html) for an explanation and examples.

Here is a contrived example:

> *Amici mei mihi occurrerunt. **Quos** cum salutavissem, domum reversus sum.*
>   I ran into my friends. Having greeted **them**, I returned home.

In your passage, you can read *quem* as if it was *eum* (= *puerum*), but the use or relative instead of demonstrative is indeed idiomatic and pretty common in Latin.
This kind of connecting relative seems to be quite common with *cum*.